# Jenkinsfile - Pipeline job stuck at input() step

Tags: terraform, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, terragrunt

I'm running terraform pipeline through Jenkinsfile, where I'm using a `input(...)` block for the user approval, before apply. This is the code snippet:

```
stage('tf_plan') {

  agent {
    label: 'Jenkins-Linux-Dev'
  }

  steps {
    sh(
      label: 'Terraform Plan',
      script: '''
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        terraform plan -input=false -no-color -out=plan.tfplan'
      '''
    )
  }
}
stage('tf_approve') {

  when { expression { return env.Action == 'apply' } }

  options {
    timeout( time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES' )
  }  
  steps {
    input(
      message: 'Proceed with above Terraform Plan??',
      ok: 'Proceed'
    )
  }
}
stage('tf_apply') {

  agent {
    label: 'Jenkins-Linux-Dev'
  }

  when { expression { return env.Action == 'apply' } }

  steps {
    sh(
      label: 'Terraform Apply',
      script: '''
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false -no-color plan.tfplan'
      '''
    )
  }
}
```

`stage('tf_plan')` is working absolutely fine but when `env.Action = 'apply'`, it's not moving any further after `stage('tf_approve')`. It's stuck at `Proceed or Abort` step - not moving forward at all clicking either of 'em. Any idea what might be the problem?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

-S

Answer (score 0):

My setup:

- Jenkins 2.277.1
- Groovy 2.3
- Pipeline 2.6
- Pipeline Utility Steps 2.6.1

And the following code works fine:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    choice(choices: ['-', 'apply'], name: 'Action')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Trigger Promotion') {
      when { expression { return env.Action == 'apply' } }
      options {
        timeout( time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES' )
      }  
      steps {
        script {
          input(
            message: 'Proceed with above Terraform Plan??',
            ok: 'Proceed'
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore, I don't think the issue is with the input step. Need more info on what's going on with Jenkins and its workers at that moment. Try grabbing logs of Jenkins main node.

P.S.: I'd suggest avoiding PascalCase variables in Groovy. It's usually used to declare classses

Comment: thanks for replying. I'm fairly new to the Groovy side of the Jenkins and still trying to gt my head around. One things I noticed: The link provided by `Proceed` (or _Abort_) doesn't seem to have any target, it's like: `https://<jenkins_host>/jobs/my-job/150/console#` - is this the way it should be?

Comment: there's nothing that obvious (to me) in the system log but found one exception in there, where it says: `Caught exception evaluating: it.transientActions in https://<jenkins_host>/jobs/my-job/150/console. Reason: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: you must override the new overload of isApplicable in hudson.plugins.project_inheritance.projects.rebuild.RebuildValidatorSuppressor ...` - is somethig related?

Comment: I think the problem is that your OP, the `input()` call is not wrapped within a `script{}` block.